# How to \input using relative or absolute path (in plain TeX)

Tags: tex-core, input, plain-tex

I'd like to have my personal library of macros but I do not know how to import them from different directories other than the current one. And It feels super ugly to have symlinks to all files in my library or something like this.
Thanks for any directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\input foo/bar/file.tex
```

inputs `file.tex` in the relative directory `foo/bar` relative to the working directory from where tex is run (which is usually but not necessarily the directory with your main file)

Or better for files used in multiple projects, just use

```
\input file
```

and put `file.tex` in a directory listed in the TEXINPUTS kpse or shell variable. In texlive for example `~/texmf/tex/plain/mystuff/file.tex` should be in the TEXINPUTS path by default.